# Updating/adding entry to table only when question is answered?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm setting up a database in MS Access 2013, and want to ask the user a yes/no if they want to save or discard their non-saved record or edit before navigating away from the current record in my Access form.

The user should not be met with the question if pressing either the "add record" or "save" buttons.

Can someone point to where my problematic code is / or what I need?

Also, I'm new to Access, so please be gentle.

I have tried a few different guides or other answers around the web, but haven't gotten exactly to where I want to be.

My code is as such (cbotxt_Change and Form_Load relate to other parts of the form)

```
Private blnGood As Boolean

Option Compare Database

Private Sub cbotxt_Change()
    Me.txt1.Value = Me.test1.Column(2)
    Me.txt2.Value = Me.test1.Column(3)
    Me.txt3.Value = Me.test1.Column(4)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub

Private Sub button_addRecord_Click()
    blnGood = True
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    blnGood = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strMsg As String

    If Not blnGood Then
        strMsg = "want to abort?"
        If MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Yes") = vbYes Then
            Me.Undo
        Else
            Yes = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Using the code above, "want to abort?" is asked whenever the user is attempting to navigate away from the current record + when "add record" or "save" buttons are pressed. If the user answers "No", then the entry will save and the action in question be performed, except the "add record" button, which only seems to save now, not add a new record.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a little convoluted to me. Try with:

```vb
Private Sub button_addRecord_Click()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim strMsg As String

    strMsg = "want to abort?"

    If MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "New Entry") = vbYes Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Undo   ' or let the user press Escape.
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I now get the error that I can't save the record at the current time, if I try to exit the form via "x" in the right upper corner and the question is still asked when pressing the "add record" and "save" button.
Since "blnGood" is no longer used in the code, I've deleted the first line of my code, but that didn't help.

Comment: That's where _Esc_ comes in. Using Access, users should learn when to press Esc.

Comment: ah okay, so I/the user shouldn't use "X", but instead Esc until the form is cleared and can be exited without being prompted with the question? Is it possible to create an exception so the user is not questioned when using the buttons?

Comment: This will quickly get messy because you will be fighting the default behaviour of Access. One "option" is to remove the X-close option from the title bar.

Comment: so the easiest would be to reverse the question, making it a "Would you like to save entry?" question instead? sounds like a plan, thank you!